# Bidirectional binding fails to bind

Tags: scala, data-binding, javafx, scalafx

Here is an example from Pro ScalaFX:

```
package proscalafx.ch03

import scalafx.beans.property.StringProperty

object BidirectionalBindingExample extends App {
  println("Constructing two StringProperty objects.")
  val prop1 = new StringProperty("")
  val prop2 = new StringProperty("")

  println("Calling bindBidirectional (<==>).")
  prop2 <==> prop1

  println("prop1.isBound = " + prop1.isBound)
  println("prop2.isBound = " + prop2.isBound)

  println("Calling prop1.set(\"prop1 says: Hi!\")")
  prop1() = "prop1 says: Hi!"
  println("prop2.get returned:")
  println(prop2())

  println( """Calling prop2.set(prop2.get + "\nprop2 says: Bye!")""")
  prop2() = prop2() + "\nprop2 says: Bye!"
  println("prop1.get returned:")
  println(prop1())
}
```

The two `StringProperty` objects are supposed to be bound with each other, when one of them is updated, the other should be also updated. This isn't true here:

```
Constructing two StringProperty objects.
Calling bindBidirectional (<==>).
prop1.isBound = false
prop2.isBound = false
Calling prop1.set("prop1 says: Hi!")
prop2.get returned:
prop1 says: Hi!
Calling prop2.set(prop2.get + "\nprop2 says: Bye!")
prop1.get returned:
prop1 says: Hi!
prop2 says: Bye!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with this code. `prop1` and `prop2` are bi-directionally bound to each other. When you look at the output you provided it is clearly the case. When value of `prop1` was set to "prop1 says: Hi!" value of `prop2` changes to it too, and when you change `prop2` then `prop1` is changing. Please look carefully at the output.

One thing that may be confusing is that `isBound` returns `false` for both properties. This is correct behaviour for bi-directional binding. `isBound` will return true only if a property is uni-directionally bound to another. So if you would change the code to:

```
prop2 <== prop1
println("prop1.isBound = " + prop1.isBound)
println("prop2.isBound = " + prop2.isBound)
```

You would get

```
prop1.isBound = false
prop2.isBound = true
```

This is how JavaFX works, nothing to do with ScalaFX.